# How to Control async method react-native

Tags: react-native

*I want to send data to another component. I get datas from*

> AsyncStorage.getItem('myKey');

*But when start async, component start to render so it sends null data to another component.*

**here is my methods ;**

```
  componentWillMount(){
          this.getdata(); 
        }

    getdata =  async () => {
  console.log("console1");
          const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('myKey');
    console.log("console2");
          let valuePrsed = JSON.parse(value);
          if(valuePrsed.username != null && valuePrsed.password != null)
          {
                this.setState({values: valuePrsed});

          }
        }
```

**and this is my render method ;**

```
 render() {

      console.log("rende splashscreen: ", this.state.values);
      let { fadeAnim } = this.state;
        return (
          <View style = {{flex:1}}>

          <LoginForm  profile = {this.state.values}/>

            <Animated.View style={{ ...this.props.style, opacity: fadeAnim }} >
            {this.props.children}

              <ImageBackground style={styles.logo1} source={require('../../image/dataLogo.jpeg')} >

                </ImageBackground>

            </Animated.View>

          </View>

        );
    }
```

*I send datas to LoginForm. I want to ask one more question. If I use `<LoginForm />` like this, it ruins my component. How can I send with different way ?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only render if it's ready to render. the way I do it is initialize a state lets say `isReady` and set to `false` then set it to `true` when you have the value. 
Would look like this:

```
    export default class test extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
       isReady:false
    }
}

     componentWillMount(){
          this.getdata(); 
        }

    getdata =  async () => {
         const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('myKey');
         this.setState({isReady:true})
          let valuePrsed = JSON.parse(value);
          if(valuePrsed.username != null && valuePrsed.password != null)
          {
                this.setState({values: valuePrsed});

          }
        }
    render() {
        if(this.state.isReady){
        return (
            <View ref={ref => this.view = ref} onLayout={() => this.saveLayout()}>

            </View>
        )}else{
            <View></View>
        }
    }
}
```

To your second question:
If you pass through LoginForm you can create a function there that gets the parameters and updates state, then pass that function to your other component and call the function with the values in paremeter. if you are using react navigation you can do it like so:
**loginForm**

```
updateValues(values){
   this.setState({value:values})
}
```

To pass the function with react-navigation:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('otherComponent',{updateValues:this.updateValues})
```

In your otherComponent you call the function like so:
**otherComponent**

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.updateValues(newValues);
```

Comment: oh this is work. but I put return null into else.  can u answer my second question ?

Comment: I didn't understand your second question. can you explain better please

Comment: I want to pass datas which is in values to LoginForm component. But if ı want to send like my way,  my splashscreen ruins. because  loginform comes to my splashscreen so splashscreen shows login form and splash. it should show just splashscreen. I want to pass values to loginform just

Comment: I'm not sure if i got it. Do you want to navigate to LoginForm or do you want to include it in that screen?

Comment: I just want to pass data to LoginForm . I dont want to include that screen and I dont want to open loginScreen. Just need to send data and change states in loginscreen

Comment: ok got it. When your are in that screen do you pass through LoginForm first?

Comment: yeah bro just pass data to loginForm not open  or I dont want include loginScreen in splashscreen

Comment: Yeah I know this way. But if I use navigate, it shows that page on screen ?

Answer (score 0):

How about checking for the values variable in the render method?

render() {

```
  console.log("rende splashscreen: ", this.state.values);
  let { fadeAnim } = this.state;

    return (
      this.state.values ?
        <View style = {{flex:1}}>

        <LoginForm  profile = {this.state.values}/>

        <Animated.View style={{ ...this.props.style, opacity: fadeAnim }} >
        {this.props.children}

          <ImageBackground style={styles.logo1} source={require('../../image/dataLogo.jpeg')} >

            </ImageBackground>

        </Animated.View>

      </View>
      : <></>
    );
}
```

Comment: I see. Well, you could have a check in the render method for the values variable. I will update my answer with the suggestion

Comment: look my getdata method I edited. first console1 comes then  values comes empty which is in render, then console2 comes

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a default/initial values in state variable at first like this:

```
constructor(props){
  this.state = {
     values:{userName: '', password: ''}
}
}
```

And when the actual values are available you can set them in state and automatically re-rendering will occur.
Since AsyncStorage returns a promise you can use .then() syntax

```
componentDidMount(){
  console.log("console1");
         AsyncStorage.getItem('myKey').then(value=>{
      let valuePrsed = JSON.parse(value);
      if(valuePrsed.username != null && valuePrsed.password != null)
          {
                this.setState({values: valuePrsed});

          }
}).catch(err=>{
  console.log('err', err);
})              
}
```

Comment: İf  I use componentDidMount, componen will be render before componentDidMount start. but I need to get values before render start.

Comment: yes but eventually your the state will change and re-rendering will happen, you can also use componentWillMount.

Comment: it is not work  :/, when code comes to  AsyncStorage.getItem('myKey') it goes to render method. I dont wait to finish AsyncStorage.getItem('myKey').then....